Tensorflow Understanding Conv2D
Beginner using Tensorflow. Started reading the documentation and checking the examples provided in the website:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/cnn
From a mathematical point of view I understand the convolution, but it is not clear to me how it is implemented using Conv2D.
From the second link, the convolution is implemented as:
layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3))
From the convolution point of view, how is the filter defined by only one number? How does the convolution works in Tensorflow?
Thanks,
Gus

Lets first explain and consider your input size.
Imagine a small RGB image of size 32x32x3:

Height (32 pixels): This is the number of rows in the image.
Width (32 pixels): This is the number of columns in the image.
Channels (3): Each pixel has three color values (R, G, B).


image taken from here.
The parameters in a Conv2D Layer you use are (without considering the rest):

activation: This is the activation function applied to the output of the convolution. relu (rectified linear unit) is a common activation function. I guess you are not asking about this parameter.

kernel_size: This is (3, 3) in your example. It defines the dimensions of the convolution window (height and width of the filter). A 3x3 kernel means the filter is a 3x3 matrix. Note that since your input_size has 3 channels by default your filters are 3x3x3 where the last 3 is always equal to the number of channels of the input_shape. Assumptions likes these make Keras/tf easier to use for common use cases like chaining together Conv2ds in deep convolutional networks.

number of filters: Essentially, it defines how many different filters (or kernels) will be learned by the layer (in your case of 32 filters size 3x3x3). This means that 32 different filters will be learn by a single Conv2D Layer.


Each of the 32 filters will be convolve against your input data to give a 32x32x1 matrix (considering padding="same"). These 32 (one per filter  32x32x1) matrices are stacked along the depth dimension, resulting in an output tensor with dimensions slightly less than (or equal to, if padding is used) 32x32x32. This data will be output to the next layer if it is another Conv2D you can again decide the parameters lets consider:

the number of filter: 64
kernel_size: 5x5.

In this layer your convolutional filters will be 5x5x32 (32 is the number of channels from the previous layer) and you will have 64 of these filters that the layer will learn.
Hope this helps you
